# Loading an R package without all the names in it

Tags: r

I'm sorry if this a duplicate, but it's un-internet-searchable.

I would like to load `ggplot`, but without littering my global namespace with all the functions therein.

I am content with accessing the functions as `ggplot2::aes()`, and I don't want just `aes()` to work.

In other programming languages, this is the default behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have really answered this yourself.  This works without any `library` statements as long as ggplot2 is installed:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(BOD, ggplot2::aes(Time, demand)) + ggplot2::geom_point()
```

This could alternately be done like this:

```
ggplot <- ggplot2::ggplot
aes <- ggplot2::aes
geom_point <- ggplot2::geom_point
ggplot(BOD, aes(Time, demand)) + geom_point()
```

Another possibility is to just temporarily add ggplot2 and then remove it again:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(BOD, aes(Time, demand)) + geom_point()
detach("package:ggplot2", unload = TRUE)
```

There are a number of R packages which provide facilities that may be of interest including the modules and import packages on CRAN.  Also the klmr modules R package on github (not on CRAN) provides a Python-like framework.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I could access it without doing `library` first.

I can post this as a follow-up, but is it possible to list the names that I want to pull into the global namespace?

Something like `from ggplot2 import aes, ggplot`

Comment: Have moved my comments to the answer.